# Can't navigate through my different router-link using VueRouter

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm working for the first time with a project created using vue-cli. I'm using VueRouter to navigate between multiple views. The problem is that if I visit de route '/workshops', '/categories' or '/machines', it's always the 'Workshops' component that show up...
Here's my router declaration:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter, { RouteConfig } from 'vue-router'
import Home from '../views/Home.vue'
import Categories from '../views/Categories.vue';
import Machines from '../views/Machines.vue';
import Workshops from '../views/Workshops.vue';

Vue.use(VueRouter)

const routes: Array<RouteConfig> = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'Home',
    component: Home
  },
  {
    path: '/categories',
    name: 'Categories',
    component: Categories
  },
  {
    path: '/machines',
    name: 'Machines',
    component: Machines
  },
  {
    path: '/workshops',
    name: 'Workshops',
    component: Workshops
  },
  {
    path: '/about',
    name: 'About',
    // route level code-splitting
    // this generates a separate chunk (about.[hash].js) for this route
    // which is lazy-loaded when the route is visited.
    component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "about" */ '../views/About.vue')
  }
]

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes
})

export default router
```

Which is pretty similar to what is declared by default
And here is the declaration of the Workshop component (but Machines and Categories uses the exact same structure)

```
<template>
    <div class="workshops">
        <h1>Workshops</h1>
    </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
    import Vue from 'vue'
    export default class Workshops extends Vue {

    }
</script>
```

And Categories.vue as an example:

```
<template>
    <div class="categories">
        <h1>Catégories</h1>
    </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
    import { Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator';
    export default class Categories extends Vue {}
</script>
```

The main App.vue is declared as following:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <header>
        <nav>
            <h2 class="brand-name">Flexshop</h2>
            <hr>
            <ul>
              <li><router-link to="/workshops">Ateliers</router-link></li>
              <li><router-link to="/categories">Catégories</router-link></li>
              <li><router-link to="/machines">Machines</router-link></li>
            </ul>

            <div class="bottom">
                <ul>
                    <router-link to="/settings">Options</router-link>
                    <router-link to="/credits">Crédits</router-link>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <main>
      <transition name="fade">
        <router-view></router-view>
      </transition>
    </main>
  </div>
</template>
```

If I only use one of the three routes in the router declarations, the correct component shows up, it seems like the declaration the latest components overwrite the two others...

Thanks for your help !

Comment: It would help to see the script in one of the other components. Is it possible that you made a mistake on your exports declaration? Like, "export default class Workshops" in your Categories component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use component decorator, like this

```
<template>
    <div class="workshops">
        <h1>Workshops</h1>
    </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
    import { Component, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator';
    
    @Component
    export default class Workshops extends Vue {

    }
</script>
```